# CSS div height & width not be applied

Tags: html, css, next.js, tailwind-css

For some reason I am unable to apply height and width to div elements. I am using TailwindCSS and Nextjs.

My goal is to create slides to snap scroll vertically, but the height and width properties are removed in the browser.

Please any suggestions Im desperate.

This is my css for the container and each view within:

```css
  .snap-container {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
  }
  .snap-view {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
  }
```

[image]

Comment: looks like it does from the .snap-view class (others are stripped because already applied ...)

Answer (score 0):

if you had

```
.snap-container {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
  }
  .snap-view {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
  }
```

both your styles will be applied, even if on the picture you are showing only the `.snap/view`

> but the height and width properties are removed in the browser.

this is because those are other properties around the code that are above the code you posted and they may have been overwritten by that, by being cascading

if you want the `.h-screen` and `.w-full` properties to apply regardless, you can put them direclty into the element, or trying putting them in the CSS below the `.snap-container` and `.snap-view`

try that, hoping I have helped